# Error while reading file with fs.readFileSync and comparing it with a string template containing multiple line

Tags: javascript, jestjs, fs

I am trying to build a jest test for reading the contents of a .md file and comparing it with a template string. Using fs.readFileSync()
But I seem to encounter the same error again and again.

```
    Expected value:  "## Available actions·
    <!-- START_ACTIONS_LIST -->
    - [assignRegistrant](./assignRegistrant)
    - [closeIssue](./closeIssue)
    - [createFile](./createFile)
    - [createIssue](./createIssue)
    - [createLabel](./createLabel)
    - [createProjectBoard](./createProjectBoard)
    - [createPullRequest](./createPullRequest)
    - [createPullRequestComment](./createPullRequestComment)
    - [createReview](./createReview)
    - [createStatus](./createStatus)
    - [deleteBranch](./deleteBranch)
    - [findInTree](./findInTree)
    - [gate](./gate)
    - [getFileContents](./getFileContents)
    - [getIssue](./getIssue)
    - [getPullRequest](./getPullRequest)
    - [getTree](./getTree)
    - [htmlContainsTag](./htmlContainsTag)
    - [mergeBranch](./mergeBranch)
    - [mergePullRequest](./mergePullRequest)
    - [octokit](./octokit)
    - [removeBranchProtection](./removeBranchProtection)
    - [requestReviewFromRegistrant](./requestReviewFromRegistrant)
    - [respond](./respond)
    - [updateBranchProtection](./updateBranchProtection)·
    <!-- END_ACTIONS_LIST -->
    "
    Received string: "## Available actions···
    <!-- START_ACTIONS_LIST -->·
    - [assignRegistrant](./assignRegistrant)·
    - [closeIssue](./closeIssue)·
    - [createFile](./createFile)·
    - [createIssue](./createIssue)·
    - [createLabel](./createLabel)·
    - [createProjectBoard](./createProjectBoard)·
    - [createPullRequest](./createPullRequest)·
    - [createPullRequestComment](./createPullRequestComment)·
    - [createReview](./createReview)·
    - [createStatus](./createStatus)·
    - [deleteBranch](./deleteBranch)·
    - [findInTree](./findInTree)·
    - [gate](./gate)·
    - [getFileContents](./getFileContents)·
    - [getIssue](./getIssue)·
    - [getPullRequest](./getPullRequest)·
    - [getTree](./getTree)·
    - [htmlContainsTag](./htmlContainsTag)·
    - [mergeBranch](./mergeBranch)·
    - [mergePullRequest](./mergePullRequest)·
    - [octokit](./octokit)·
    - [removeBranchProtection](./removeBranchProtection)·
    - [requestReviewFromRegistrant](./requestReviewFromRegistrant)·
    - [respond](./respond)·
    - [updateBranchProtection](./updateBranchProtection)···
    <!-- END_ACTIONS_LIST -->·
    "
```

The Jest function is as follow:

```
it('README mentions all expected actions', async () => {
    const actionsReadme = fs.readFileSync(path.join(actionsDir, 'README.md'), { encoding: 'utf8' })
    const expectedContents = `## Available actions

<!-- START_ACTIONS_LIST -->
${actionNames.map(name => `- [${name}](./${name})`).join('\n')}

<!-- END_ACTIONS_LIST -->
`
    expect(actionsReadme).toContainEqual(expectedContents);
  })
```

And my README.md file is as follow:

```
## Available actions

<!-- START_ACTIONS_LIST -->
- [assignRegistrant](./assignRegistrant)
- [closeIssue](./closeIssue)
- [createFile](./createFile)
- [createIssue](./createIssue)
- [createLabel](./createLabel)
- [createProjectBoard](./createProjectBoard)
- [createPullRequest](./createPullRequest)
- [createPullRequestComment](./createPullRequestComment)
- [createReview](./createReview)
- [createStatus](./createStatus)
- [deleteBranch](./deleteBranch)
- [findInTree](./findInTree)
- [gate](./gate)
- [getFileContents](./getFileContents)
- [getIssue](./getIssue)
- [getPullRequest](./getPullRequest)
- [getTree](./getTree)
- [htmlContainsTag](./htmlContainsTag)
- [mergeBranch](./mergeBranch)
- [mergePullRequest](./mergePullRequest)
- [octokit](./octokit)
- [removeBranchProtection](./removeBranchProtection)
- [requestReviewFromRegistrant](./requestReviewFromRegistrant)
- [respond](./respond)
- [updateBranchProtection](./updateBranchProtection)

<!-- END_ACTIONS_LIST -->
```

I don't seem to understand the bullet at the end of the line in the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

The dots show were differences are. Most like the newlines in the source file are different from what Javascript considers to be "\n". Either you fix that, or you piece your expected result together from a list of strings.

```
const expectedContents = [
    '## Available actions',
    '<!-- START_ACTIONS_LIST -->',
    actionNames.map(name => `- [${name}](./${name})`),
    '<!-- END_ACTIONS_LIST -->'
].flat.join('\n').concat('\n');
```

Comment: I am afraid, it's not working. I am still getting the error and I search online, `flat` is still not compatible everywhere.

Comment: Not the best solution but once I removed the new lines from both the variables storing the string and the file content, using:

```javascript
expect(actionsReadme.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"")).toContain(expectedContents.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,""))
```

The comparison was successful. So thank you for pointing me to right direction.